# $S^1$ is the only compact connected 1-manifold.

Tags: manifolds

I want to find a proof of $S^1$ is the only compact connected 1-manifold. (In here, manifold means Hausdorff, locally euclidean space) Is there any reference? Or is it easy and can be proved simply?

Comment: A proof can be found in the appendix of Milnor's _Topology from the Differentiable Viewpoint_.

Comment: Milnor only covers the case of smooth manifolds, but the result is the same for topological. You can find an unpublished write-up of a proof by googling classification of 1-manifolds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a proof in [*Introduction to Topological Manifolds*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441979395) by John Lee. It is a section on the classification of $1$-dimensional manifolds under the chapter on cell complexes.