# What is the topological classification of connected 1-manifolds?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, connectedness

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The only 1-manifolds are $\mathbb R$ and $S^1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113705/the-only-1-manifolds-are-mathbb-r-and-s1)

Any manifold is homeomorphic to the disjoint sum of its connected components. Therefore, the full classification of manifolds of dimension 1 reduces to the study of connected manifolds.

Could you please give a proof (sketch) as well or link to a good reference on the subject?

Comment: I just edited your question slightly. You might want to click on the link after "edited" to make sure I didn't distort your meaning. :) This question has been asked at least twice before [[1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221311/s1-is-the-only-compact-connected-1-manifold)] [[2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221311/s1-is-the-only-compact-connected-1-manifold)]. I don't know if there's a full proof anywhere on this site, but there are a few different references in the comments/answers to those questions.

Comment: another question with sketch of proof  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1866339/how-to-prove-that-there-are-only-two-kinds-of-1-dim-manifolds-without-boundary

Answer (score 1):

Any connected manifold of dimension 1 is diffeomorphic to the circle or to the line.
If you can read french : Introduction aux variétés différentielles, Jacques Lafontaine.

Comment: Why down-vote ?

Comment: There are 4 connected 1-manifolds: the line, the circle, the long line, and the open long ray.

Comment: Are you serious ? The last two ones are not paracompact... So if you want to take it like this, YOU ARE WRONG because there are other non-Haussdorf manifolds.

Answer (score 1):

Line in the case of smooth manifolds, up to homeomorphism, there are only 2 connected 1-dimensional manifolds: the circle and the real line. You can find the proof of that fact - at least in the smooth case - in Milnor's classical text *"Topology from a differentiable viewpoint"*, which is something always worth reading, and also in many places in the internet, for example [here](http://www.math.ist.utl.pt/~ggranja/TD/08/classif1manifs.pdf).