# How to prove that there are only two kinds of 1-dim manifolds without boundary

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, geometric-topology

I just know a conclusion that all 1-dim manifolds without boundary is homomorphism to $S^1$ or $\mathbb{R}$ , but I don't know how to prove it . Why is so ?

Comment: In munkres topology 2 edition which is online and free, you can find on chapter four a complete answer to the imbedding of manifold question.

Comment: Every _connected_ one-manifold without boundary is homeomorphic to a circle or open interval. There's an elementary proof in _Differential Topology_ by Guillemin and Pollack. The intuitive idea is easy enough: Fix a point arbitrarily, and exhaust by compact intervals. If the ends join up in the limit, you're on a circle. If not, you're on an open interval.

Comment: Reference : Appendix in J. Milnor's beautiful book  _Topology from the Differential Viewpoint_

Comment: Interestingly, you need to use both the Hausdorff condition and second countability for this result to be true. The line with two origins and the long line give counterexamples otherwise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here a sketch of the proof.

Suppose that $M$ is a smooth 1-dimensional manifold.

Let's first suppose that $M$ is orientable. This means that we can find a global top-dimensional never-vanishing differential form over $M$, i.e. (up to fixing a Riemannian metric over $M$) a never-vanishing global vector field $X \in \Gamma(TM)$.

It is easy to check (the details are up to you) that a flow line $\gamma: \mathbb{R} \to M$ of $X$ gives either a diffeomorphism $M \simeq \mathbb{R}$ , or  a periodic map (with say period $T$) that descends to  a diffeomorphism $M \simeq \mathbb{R}/T \mathbb{Z} \simeq S^1$.

Now we have just to rule out the evenience that there are non-orientable 1-dimensional manifolds. 
In order to do this suppose that $M$ is non-orientable and consider its universal cover $\widetilde{M}$. This is an orientable 1-diemnsional manifold (in fact, it is simply connected), and you can check (using what we proved so far) that $\widetilde{M}\simeq \mathbb{R}$.

Now, if $M$ is non-orientable, there is $\gamma \in \pi_1(M)$ acting on the universal covering $\widetilde{M}\simeq \mathbb{R}$ as an orientation-reversing diffeomorphism. In order to obtain the contradiction, notice (this is elementary analysis) that an orientation reversing diffeomorphism of the real line always has a fixed point.

Comment: This assumes the manifold is smooth.

Comment: I know man, life is a sad story. I'm sorry for the inconvenience. :)

Comment: How does the existence of fixed point give a contradiction?