# One-dimensional manifold classification

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds

I have read in several books that a connected paracompact Hausdorff one-dimensional manifold without boundary points is homeomorphic to the circle if it is compact. However I dont figure out how to prove it.

Rougly speaking, I if the one-dimension manifold is connected, it is homeomorphic to a interval in the real line, but an interval is not homeomorphic to the circle, Am I wrong?

Comment: Look at Guillemin and Pollack's Differential Topology or Milnor's book for a proof if you consider smooth maifolds. For topological manifolds i think i've seen in Lee's Introduction to Topological Manifolds.

Comment: if the manifold is paracompact but not compact it is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$, if it is however compact, to $S^1$. So just two options in one-dimension (for *connected* manifolds, of course).

Comment: A $1$-dimensional manifold is *locally* homeomorphic to an open interval in $\Bbb R$. But you forgot about the hypothesis of compactness.

Comment: A space is compact provided each its open cover has a finite subcover. The circle is compact, the real line is not.