# If $X$ is a connected $n$-dim manifold and $Y \subseteq X$ a proper subspace. Prove that $H_n(Y;\mathbb{Z}) \to H_n(X;\mathbb{Z})$ is the zero map.

Tags: algebraic-topology

> If $X$ is a connected $n$-dimensional manifold and $Y \subseteq X$ a proper subspace. Prove that $H_n(Y;\mathbb{Z}) \to H_n(X;\mathbb{Z})$ is the zero map.

My idea was to look at the long exact sequence in homology and use exactness properties to deduce that $H_n(Y;\mathbb{Z}) \to H_n(X;\mathbb{Z})$ is in fact the zero map. I'm pretty sure that $H_{n+1}(X, Y;\mathbb{Z}) =0 $ which would imply that $H_n(Y;\mathbb{Z}) \to H_n(X;\mathbb{Z})$ has trivial kernel.

If I can show that $H_n(X;\mathbb{Z})\to H_n(X, Y ;\mathbb{Z})$ has trivial kernel then I would be done by exactness, but I don't see any reason why this should hold which leads me to believe that there might be some other approach to attack this problem that I'm not seeing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The case $n = 0$ is trivial. So let us assume $n  \ge 1$.

It suffices to consider the case $Y(x) = X \setminus \{x\}$ with $x \in X$ because each inclusion $Y \hookrightarrow X$ factors through some $Y(x)$. The space $Y(x)$ is a non-compact manifold. For $n \ge 2$ it is connected, thus $H_n(Y(x)) = 0$ and the result follows. See Proposition 3.29 in Hatcher. For $n = 1$ we need a special argument.

Case 1. $Y(x)$ is connected. Then again $H_1(Y(x)) = 0$.

Case 2. $Y(x)$ is not connected. This is possible only when $X \approx \mathbb R$ (see [The only 1-manifolds are $\mathbb R$ and $S^1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/113705)). Then $H_1(X) = 0$.

Comment: Very nice - I was worried about, e.g., taking $Y\subseteq S^3$ to be the sphere version of the Hawaiian earring, so that $H_3(Y)$ is large.  I like how using $Y(x)$ just skirts all these issues.